# Showing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[]{m})\neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[]{m},\sqrt[]{n})$

Tags: galois-theory, radicals

Let $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ be square free integers such that $m\neq n$

Show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[]{m})\neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[]{m},\sqrt[]{n})$

My approach to doing this is showing that $\sqrt[]{m}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[]{n})$

I am trying to do this currently by supposing by contradiction that we could write $\sqrt[]{m}$ as

$$\frac{a+b\sqrt[]{n}}{c+d\sqrt[]{n} }$$

By rationalizing the denominator we get

$$c\sqrt[]{m}+d\sqrt[]{mn}-b\sqrt[]{n}=a$$

I have other results, but the important thing is if I can show that the sum on the left is not a rational, I am done

I know that all the roots are distinct (even if the middle one reduces a little)

Is there a result about finite rational sums of square roots that could help show that this result is not possible? (Since $m\neq n$ we know all the roots are different square free integers)

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest: take the $b\sqrt{n}$ to the other side, and square both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $$\sqrt{m}=a+b\sqrt{n}$$ with $a$ and $b$ rational then

$$m=a^2+b^2n+2ab\sqrt{n}$$ this is only possible if $ab=0$, and $b\neq 0$ from the first equation, so $a=0$ and we have 
$$\sqrt{m}=b\sqrt{n}$$ so $mn$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Are there results about finite sums of rational multiples of distinct square roots?

Comment: @northcity4 Yes, they are linearly independent, so you can generalize the result.

Comment: How would you justify that they are linearly independent? I have never seen that result before. Possibly a good article/link you could suggest?

Comment: @northcity4 This is a minor famous result. I dont have a ref, but if you google it I think youll find some manuscripts. I think it also follows from Kummer theory, but perhaps its more elementary than that.

Comment: Here is it its not that hard if $\sqrt{k}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n},\sqrt{m})$ then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{k})$ is a subfield of degree $2$. But we know the subfields of degree $2$ are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$,$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$,$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{mn})$ and it cannot equal any of these by the case just proven. In general the induction is the same.

Comment: Actually Kummer theory gives immediately a solution. If $Q(                                  \sqrt m, \sqrt n)= Q(\sqrt m)$, one would have $Q(\sqrt m)=Q(\sqrt n)$, and Kummer tells you that this is equivalent to $m/n \in {Q^*}^2$, which is impossible with your hypotheses on $m, n$. You will notice that the different approaches (by Kummer or by linear independence) all boil down to the fact that Z is a UFD. But the advantage of Kummer is to use the *multiplicative* structure, which is of course the natural setting for the UFD property. The result can be extended ...

Comment: ... to an arbirary finite number of square roots without much effort. Let S  the multiplicative subgroup of $Q^*/{Q^*}^2$ generated by be a finite set of integers $m_i$ . Then S can be viewed as a vector space over the finite field $F_2$ (how?), say of dimension $s$. Then, by induction, $Q(..., \sqrt m_i , ...)$ has degree $2^s$ over $Q$.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo Yes, I think I indicated that in my other comments, Kummer also allows to treat any number of surds $\sqrt[k]{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

I think you’ve made things too difficult for yourself by taking a quotient of two expressions of form $A+B\sqrt n$. After all, you have
$$
\frac{a+b\sqrt n}{c+d\sqrt n}=\frac{(a+b\sqrt n)(c-d\sqrt n)}{c^2-nd^2}=A+B\sqrt n\,,
$$
for rational numbers $A$ and $B$ that you can figure out as easily as I can.

Then you just want to show that for rational numbers $A$ and $B$, it is not possible to have $(A+B\sqrt n)^2=m$, and I think you should be able to do that without much trouble.

Comment: In this case, it is true that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[]{n})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[]{n}]$ and your solution is justified, but is there a result about rational multiples of finite sums of distinct square roots?

Comment: Yes, there is, but the general proof is too long to fit in this margin. The result is that if $S$ is a set of elements (of $\Bbb C$, for instance) that are each algebraic over a field $k$, then $k[S]=k(S)$.